# Windows 7 boots in normal mode but not in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, boot

This is very strange. I've recently found that my Windows 7 PC boots normally but won't boot into Safe mode from the F8 menu. It starts in Safe mode (shows the files being loaded) but then re-boots into normal mode. I have forced it by setting the boot into Safe mode from msconfig, but then it kept looping until I managed to stop it and chose "last good configuration". Short of re-installing Windows 7, has anyone got a solution?

Comment: At what point it looped? maybe while loading a specific driver?

Comment: How can I find that out? Safe Mode runs through to "Loading ... Classpnp.sys" as normal, then "Please wait" and "Welcome" are shown against the normal Windows background, then it reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions 
1. Reset your computer by removing the bios battery or

2. Try this
3. Boot into Windows Recovery Mode
4. Open command prompt
5. Type: 
   sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=C:\  /OFFWINDIR=C:\Windows

Or try this 
1. Enter BIOS - ADVANCED - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION - SATA CONTROLLER MODE - and changed it to COMPATIBILITY mode.

or this 
1. Boot the computer to windows recovery mode.
2. Click Commmad Prompt, type in:
rename c:\windows\system32\drivers\classpnp.sys classpnp.old

or lastly

Try a in-place upgrade to repair the corrupted files:

## In-place Upgrade

1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD in the computer's DVD drive.
2. Click Start and choose Computer.
3. Please find the "setup.exe" file in the DVD-ROM and double click it.
4. Click Install now.
5. When we are prompted to input the product key, please click Next without inputting any key. The setup wizard will prompt and ask if you agree to install Windows 7 without the key. Please choose to confirm.
6. When you reach the "Which type of installation do you want" screen, click Upgrade to upgrade the system files of Windows Vista.

   or 
   just reinstall windows

Comment: I've tried all you have suggested down to "or lastly" but the PC still won't boot into any of the Safe Mode options from the "F8" menu. If these are chosen, all the drivers are loaded and I get a "Please wait" and "Welcome" with the normal cloudy Windows background splash screen, then the PC re-boots. However as it does run normally I'm extremely reluctant to re-install Windows 7 until a calamity occurs. I think I would have difficulties with a Repair Install as the original DVD is a pre-SP1 upgrade, so I don't think a Repair Install would work either. System Restore didn't work.

Comment: What about running **sfc /scannow** while booted to Windows 7 in normal mode ? Does it finish without errors ?